# Force CMake to install targets to architecture-specific directories?

Tags: cmake

I'm currently having this issue with the [Google Protobuf Library](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf), but it is a recurring problem and will likely occur with many if not all 3rd-party packages that I want to build and install from source.

I'm developing for Windows, and we need to be able to generate both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of our DLLs. It was relatively straightforward to get CMake to install our own modules to architecture-specific subdirectories, e.g. `D:\libraries\bin\i686` and `d:\libraries\lib\i686` (and sim. for `bin`). But I'm having trouble achieving the same thing with 3rd-party libraries such as Protobuf.

I could, of course, use distinct `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` and `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` combinations (e.g. `D:\libraries-i686`  and `D:\libraries-x86_64`, and will probably end up doing just that, but it bothers me that there doesn't seem to be a better alternative. The [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) for `find_package()` clearly show that the search procedure does attempt architecture-specific search paths, so why do the CMake files of popular libraries not generally seem to support *installing* to architecture-specific subdirectories?

Or could it be that it is just a matter of setting the right `CMAKE_XXX` variable?

Comment: `CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`, `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` and the like?

Comment: "why do the CMake files of popular libraries not generally seem to support installing to architecture-specific subdirectories?" - Because there is no well-defined **conventions** in installing into such directories. Note, that placing `XXXConfig.cmake` script in a directory `<prefix>/lib/<arch>/cmake/<name>*/` is described in `find_package` documentation as **Unix** convention, which you attempt to use on Windows. Luckily, CMake searches all directories irrespective of the target platform.

Comment: Moreover, while [find_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html) actually searches libraries under `<prefix>/lib/<arch>`, [find_program](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_program.html) does NOT search executables under `<prefix>/bin/<arch>`. So without `XXXConfig.cmake` script the package which places its binaries under `bin/i686` wouldn't be detected by "normal" `FindXXX.cmake` script.

Comment: Thanks @tsyvarev

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes, the convention comes from Unix, but IMO it would make sense under Windows too. But no matter, Windows separates things at the root (`C:\Program Files (x86)` vs `C:\Program Files`), so it's probably best to go the same route. I didn't know about the limitation with FindXXX.cmake, but as I try to use config files exclusively, it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @arrowd for pointing me in the right direction, I now have my answer, though it is not exactly what I had hoped for.

`CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` and `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`, however, specify the *build* output directories, not the *install* directories. As it turns out though, there are variables for the install directories too, called `CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR` and `CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR` - they are actually plainly visible (along with plenty more) in the cmake-gui interface when "Advanced" is checked.

I tried setting those two manually (to `bin\i686` and `lib\i686`), and it works: the Protobuf `INSTALL` target copies the files where I wanted to have them, i.e. where the CMake script of my consumer project will find them in an architecture-safe manner.

I'm not sure how I feel about this - I would have preferred something like a `CMAKE_INSTALL_ARCHITECTURE` or `CMAKE_ARCHITECTURE_SUBDIR` variable that CMake would automatically append to relevant install paths. The solution above requires overriding defaults that I would prefer to leave untouched.

Under the circumstances, my fallback approach might still be the better option. That approach however requires that the choice of architecture be made very early on, typically when running the script that initializes the CMake-specific environment variables that will be passed to `cmake` when configuring build directories. And it's worse when using `cmake-gui`, which requires the user to set all directories manually.

In the end, I'm still undecided.

Comment: Have you tried using a generator expression in these values to distinguish platforrm?

Comment: @John That would be a great idea, except there doesn't seem to be a suitable expression. The closest I could find was `$<PLATFORM_ID>`, which however evaluates to `Windows` - not terribly helpful.